# does vbs scripting still work in windows 7/8

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

Apologies in advance for my terminology or possible lack of knowledge in this area.

This is a `*.vbs` script that will open a excell workbook `WBName = "\WorkBookName.xlsm"` (generally in the same directory as the *.vbs file)and run a macro `MacroName = "'" & strpath & WBName & "'!MacroName"` in that workbook. It will then save the workbook.

This also has a Sub called WriteLog which can receive 3 variable and be will be written tot the log file `"TestFile.txt`. And this WriteLog sub is called at some stages in the script.

My current operating system is MS Windows XP Profesionel and I use this script to open excel 2010 files for running macros.

My question is will I be able to use this script in windows7 and/or windows8? Or will I have to make some changes or rewrite it in another scripting language? And if I do what language?

```
'need to update WBName & MacroName here as this is fairly generic

dim WshShell
set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

dim strPath
strPath = WshShell.CurrentDirectory 

Dim myExcelWorker
Set myExcelWorker = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'myExcelWorker.Visible = True ' this makes excel visible 

dim oWorkBook
dim WBName

WBName = "\WorkBookName.xlsm" 'WB to be opened  

dim MacroName 
MacroName = "'" & strpath & WBName & "'!MacroName" 'Macro Name to be run 

'Write Start+strPath to log file
Call WriteLog("Start_XXX",strPath,"var3")

'Write Mid+strPath+WBName to log file
Call WriteLog("Mid___XXX",strpath & WBName,"var3")

'open WB for running macro
'set oWorkBook = myExcelWorker.Workbooks.open(strpath & WBName) 'for WB WITHOUT password 
Set oWorkBook = myExcelWorker.Workbooks.Open(strpath & WBName,,,,"","Performance") 'for WB with password

'Write MacroName to log file
Call WriteLog("Mid___XXX",MacroName,"var3")

myExcelWorker.Run MacroName

myExcelWorker.DisplayAlerts = False 'this is required so the WB will save without being prompted 

oWorkBook.Save
oWorkBook.Close

myExcelWorker.DisplayAlerts = True ' set it back to true again as it is good practice

myExcelWorker.Quit

'Write End to log file
Call WriteLog("End___XXX","t2","t3")

set oWorkBook = Nothing
set myExcelWorker = Nothing
set WshShell = Nothing

'sub to write to log file
Sub WriteLog(var1, var2, var3)

Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Wscript.Echo "VBSStart.vbs is running" 
Dim ObjFso
Dim StrFileName
Dim ObjFile
Dim FlName 

'WScript.Echo var1 & ",,,," & var2 

FlName = "TestFile.txt"
StrFileName = objShell.CurrentDirectory & "\" & FlName
Set ObjFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Creating a file for writing data
set ObjFile = ObjFso.OpenTextFile(StrFileName, 8, True) 

 'Writing a string into the file
ObjFile.WriteLine(var1 & "," & var2 & "," & var3 & "," & now)

'Closing the file
ObjFile.Close

' Using Set is mandatory
Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You could answer this question yourself by looking around the `vbscript` tagged questions here to see if any are related to Windows 7/8 and reading the questions and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VBScript` needs to run in a scripting environment. In your Windows environment, this is the [Windows Scripting Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host). According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host#Version_history), Windows 8 is shipped with WSH 5.8, but there was no reference to the source in Wikipedia unfortunately.

Comment: still on windows XP, but good to know this before I do eventually move to the next windows version.tks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It will work fine assuming you have the correct permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Yes VBS script supported in Windows 7/8, because it related with Microsoft Office Product, as you need is to have that product in your PC and it will be ok.

Comment: This answer is not in the correct context. You are assuming VBA that comes with Microsoft Office, TS asks for VBScript, the scripting language integrated into Windows. Maybe you can improve your answer for VBScript?

Comment: Thank you for your information, nothing info for right now.